# Find integral solutions for $2x^2+y^2=2\times(1007)^2+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Find integral solutions to the equation
$$2x^2+y^2=2\times(1007)^2+1$$

> I tried:
>   I rewrote the equation as $2x^2+y^2=2028099$. I found that $y_{max}=1424$ and $y$ must be odd, so I set $y=1424-(2k+1)$, where $k_{max}=711$. However I don't know how to proceed further.
>   Please Help!
>   Thanks!

Comment: Maybe rewrite the equation as $y^2-1=2(1007^2-x^2)$, so that $$(y-1)(y+1)=2(1007-x)(1007+x).$$ Now eliminate the factor of two, set the remaining equation [which will have two factors on each side] to $ab\cdot cd=ac \cdot bd$, and try to work out the possibilities. Since you already have restrictions on $max(x)$ and $max(y)$, this should be fairly easy.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan I beg your pardon, can you please elaborate?

Comment: From $(y−1)(y+1)=2(1007−x)(1007+x)$, we see that $y-1$ is even; hence $y=2z+1$ is odd. But then $4$ divides the left hand side, so $1007 \pm x$ is even, forcing $x=2w+1$ odd.

Substituting now yields
\begin{align}
((2z+1)-1)((2z+1)+1) &= 2(1007−(2w+1))(1007+(2w+1))  \\
  \frac{z(z+1)}{2} &= (503−w)(504+w).
\end{align}
Write $(z,z+1)=(2ab,cd)$ or $(ab,2cd)$, as $z$ is even or odd, respectively. Then $(503-w,504+w)=(2ac,bd)$ or $(ac,2bd)$. Now you've got lots of equations in the various unknowns, with helpful restrictions like $$(19)(53)=1007=(503-w)+(504-w)=2ac+bd \text{ or } ac+2bd.$$

Comment: Sorry, should be the single solution $(503-w,504+w)=(ac,bd)$, since the factor of $2$ cancels on the left-hand side. Then $(503-w)+(504+w)=ac+bd$, and you can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the equation modulo 2 shows that $y$ is odd.
Then looking at it modulo 4 shows that $x$ is odd as well.
(The square of an odd number is always $1\bmod4$.)

A brute force search shows that the solutions $(x,y)$ are (335,1343), (593,1151), (965,407) and (1007,1).
I fail to see enough structure in the answer to be able to explain it.